# Create Symbolic Link on network share pointing to another share

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, dfs

I am looking to create a symbolic link on the network share pointing to another network share

```
mklink /D \\Company.com\NY\data\link \\company.com\hr\application\data\
```

Is that possible? I tried it and got error "the system cannot find the path specified"

I should say I can't use shortcut for this purpose as the application I used will treat that as a file and not follow the path.

Thanks!

Comment: are both of these shares on the same server?

Comment: Not necessarily. They could be on different servers.Well, they are just one big DFS share.

Comment: try creating it when logged on the server.